# Extend PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to start using PDO (switching from MySQL extension) and I would like to add some methods but to still have the entire PDO functionality. I would like to implement a function like this:

```
$db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=:foo AND field2=:baz", array('foo'=>$foo, 'baz'=>$baz));
```

I think the best way is to extend the PDO class but in this case I would not have the instance of the class to be able to use it inside the class. Any idea?

Comment: `class DB extends PDO {}`? Then you can call PDO methods by using `$this->pdoMethod()`.

Comment: One thing that came to my mind is , runkit_method_add() . I can't think of any other way to add methods to a class .

Comment: Do not extend, but create a wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against extending PDO, but rather creating a library/wrapper around it which other ORM's do.

I will construct your example code into a simple class for explanation.

```
class MyDB
{

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function getAll($query, array $params)
    {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        return $statement->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getPdo()
    {
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    /**
     * This is called if the method cannot be found.
     * Pass it to PDO to handle.
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param $arguments
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func(array($this->pdo, $name), $arguments)
    }

}
```

If you really want to access PDO directly then I've included a magic method but I don't recommend you take that route. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Doing this sort of stuff is fun for learning, but if you want a serious ORM then take a look at this SO question [Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) and also research yourself.

Comment: Or one may choose to use one of the existing libraries already doing this :)

Comment: Yeah or that, which I would prefer!

Comment: Great example: when possible, choose composition over inheritance

Comment: Why did you edit your answer? What's wrong with creating PDO instance inside?

Comment: So you can test the class by mocking the PDO. @YourCommonSense

Comment: Thank you @FruityP but only the getAll method works. I also want to use all the PDO functionality. I want to be able to do something like this:
`$db = new Db($pdoObject);    
$users = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM users",   array('email'=>'email@gmail.com'));`
AND to also have the functionality of PDO on the same object, like this:
`$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $statement->execute(array('email'=>'email@gmail.com'));`

Comment: See edited code @denied, you can just add a getter method so `$pdo = $db->getPdo(); $pdo->prepare()` etc...

Comment: @FruityP I often write complex queries with joins and subqueries. Do you still recommend using an ORM for this kind of queries? Which one would you recommend?

Comment: @denied This is getting off the topic of the question, a simple google search on the matter will yield a plethora of information and a few SO questions. I've already linked one in the answer.

Comment: "I would advise against extending PDO" why?

Answer (score 0):

Just before you get deep in your project here is an advice for you. Do it with ORM library.

For example I am doing the same thing you need with ORM library (in this case called db.php) like this:

```
$database->path->to->table->handler->load (\db\by('field1',$value1)->by('field2',$field2));
```

The complicated thing with ORMs are that they need class definitions to work with tables and **many PHP developers are afraid of class definitions** for their data objects. For above example to work you should have needed a class definition something like this:

```
namespace \path\to;
class table
{
    public $field1;
    public $field2;
}
```

And database initialization in case of db.php ORM library like this:

```
$database = new \db\database ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1', 'test_db', 'root', '1234');
```

And class attaching to database object to handle like this:

```
$database->add ('\path\to\table');
```

Additionally many ORMs have a magic method allowing you to automatically create or generate tables according your class definitions, for example db.php (http://dbphp.net) method:

```
$database->update();
```

Will create path_to_table table in your actual mysql database with 2 fields field1 and field2.

I am not sure why people should be afraid ORMs in PHP development they make life easier for everybody and give abilities not to get confused in your own code when you are working on large scale projects.

I believe sometimes this answer will save at least 1 human from future sufferings.

: D

Answer (score -6):

a singleton example:

```
class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    final private function __construct() {}
    final private function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function getAll($sql, $data = NULL, $mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return $stmt->fetchAll($mode);
    }
}

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1=:foo AND field2=:baz";
$data = DB::getAll($sql, array('foo'=>$foo, 'baz'=>$baz));
```

Comment: Singleton is an antipattern. Just saying ... The argument "but in some cases .." isn't valid, when it's about database connections, from which you may or may not need more than once ;)

Comment: It makes me wonder, why Laravel is using a singleton all the way with database interaction. May be it is not *that* anti-pattern as some think.

Comment: "Sombody uses it, it must be best-practice"? Are you kidding?

Comment: No kidding. Laravel considered the best PHP framework to-day. I didn't say "best" though. Some people indeed think in binaries: ether practice "best" or "worst", no shades.

Comment: "The best framework" is a quite brave statement. Who said this? Whats about the other frameworks? Symfony2? ZF2? Aura? ... But #topic: Tell me, how can I access a second database? How can I test my component, that access the DB? How can I get rid of the instance, to release the resources? // Update: I had a look and what Laravel uses is an imitation of the Registry-pattern.

Comment: Well, to access another database you can use another singleton class. both extending base DB class. I see no problem with adding kill() method to the class. I am not a testing pro, but I am sure there are methods to deal with singletons.