# universal select(mysql) function using prepared statements using php language

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a universal method/function on php which uses any select statement with a where clause. However, something is not right. Can you give me a hand?

Example of using data:

```
DB inherit PDO class.
$db=new DB;
$db->select("SELECT count(*) FROM `login` WHERE Email='?'", 
            "papa1980@gmail.com");
```

Here is function

```
public function select($sqlString,...$bindParameters)
{

   $stmt=$this->prepare($sqlString);
   foreach($bindParameters as $key=>$bindParameter)
   {

       $stmt->bindParam(($key+1),$bindParameter);
       echo '<pre>' . print_r($stmt, true) . '</pre>';
   }
   echo '<pre>' . print_r($bindParameters, true) . '</pre>';
   if($stmt->execute())
   {
       echo "execution was succesful";
   }
  echo '<pre>' . print_r($stmt->fetchAll(), true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Output

PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT count(*) FROM `login` WHERE Email='?'
)

Array
(
    [0] => papa1980@gmail.com
)

execution was succesful

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count(*)] => 0
            [0] => 0
        )
)

Why is it returning 0? I use

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `login` WHERE Email='papa1980@gmail.com'
```

in mysql and it returns 1. Something is not correct in my php code.

Comment: Is your function returning anything ?

Comment: Maybe it should return `$stmt->fetchAll()` if successful and `FALSE` if not in which case you can do the condition checking where you are using this function.

Comment: Look at the answer(s) to this question and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566960/extend-pdo-class . You might also be better off using an ORM solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: I need result from each SQL to be return.Howerver as you can see    execution was succesful

Array ( [0] => Array ( [count(*)] => 0 [0] => 0 ) ) and result shall be 1

Comment: Are you getting the result from your function then ? I doubt that because your function is not returning anything.

Comment: It is working my sql was wrong.SELECT count(*) FROM `login` WHERE Email=? you shall not put ? in '' :)

Answer (score 0):

Function is working but
SELECT count(*) FROM `login` WHERE Email=? was wrong because ? shall be not in ''